# I want Facebook login for Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, facebook-login

I am developing Android using Kotlin.

I want to implement a Facebook login

I've completed the code for login, but on Android, Facebook login runs through `WebView`
But I want to connect directly to Facebook like iOS

My code:

```
val loginCallbackManager by lazy { CallbackManager.Factory.create() }

fun fbLoginClick(){
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(loginCallbackManager,object :
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
            Log.d("snsLogin","onSuccess 실행")
            val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                result?.accessToken,object : GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback{
                    override fun onCompleted(`object`: JSONObject?, response: GraphResponse?) {
                        val resultIdvalue = `object`!!.getString("id")
                        val resultEmail = `object`?.getString("email")
                    }
                }
            )
            val parameters = Bundle()
            request.parameters = parameters
            request.executeAsync()
        }
        override fun onCancel() {
            Log.d("snsLogin","onCancel실행")
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
            Log.d("snsLogin","onError실행")
        }
    })
}
```

Is there anything that needs to be changed or added in this part?

Thank you.